# Kotlin - Should reflection work for synthetic properties in Java classes

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider the following Java class:

```java
public final class Example {

    private int value;

    public int getExampleValue {
        return value;
    }

    public void setExampleValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Kotlin synthesises these get/set accessor methods as a property:

```kotlin
val example = Example()
example.exampleValue = 0 // setExampleValue(0);
val exampleValue = example.exampleValue // getExampleValue();
```

However, reflection in Kotlin does not return the synthetic property:

```kotlin
Example::class.memberProperties // [] <- list is empty!
```

So, does Kotlin not return synthetic properties via reflection?

I've tried this with:

- Kotlin 1.4.32 & JDK 8
- Kotlin 1.4.32 & JDK 11

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce on JDK 14 and Kotlin 1.4.10

Comment: @Sweeper What happens in your case?

Comment: I get the expected `[var Example.value: kotlin.Int]`. I don't have JDK 8 on my machine, so I don't know if it's actually a version problem

Comment: @Sweeper I'm curious that it works on JDK 14 (and why it works on JDK 14). Perhaps I'm missing something. I've retested it with JDK 11 as well, but still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't quite "work" because, IIUC, you expected `[var Example.exampleValue: kotlin.Int]` instead. Sweeper got the names of _fields_ instead of properties.

Comment: @k314159 That is a very good point, and well spotted! I didn't notice `value` vs. `exampleValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin compiler doesn't synthesise additional wrapper class with actually declared `exampleValue` property for this. It just translates property access syntax into getter/setter method call.

Actually, this happens even for classes declared in Kotlin.
Because this simple class:

```kotlin
class E {
    public var value = 1
}
```

is compiled *NOT* into the same bytecode as this java class:

```java
public final class E {
    public int value = 1;
}
```

but this:

```java
public final class E {
    private int value = 1;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So, when you do `.value` it's actually not a field access, but a getter call.

Kotlin reflection doesn't show you `exampleValue` field because it doesn't exist.
Yes, you can access it with property access syntax, but that's just a compiler trick.

If you want to get these "ephemeral properties" via reflection, you need to reverse-engineer that compiler's trick:

```kotlin
val getterMethodRegex = "^get\\p{Lu}.*".toRegex() //starts with 'get' followed by upper-case letter
Example::class.declaredFunctions.filter { it.name.matches(getterMethodRegex) }
```

However, this will work correctly only for classes declared in Java. For classes declared in Kotlin, compiler is not blindly replacing property access with a call to a method named like a respectful getter, but beforehand checks that there is such property:

```kotlin
class ExampleKt {
    private val value = 0
    fun getExampleValue() = value
}

ExampleKt().exampleValue //compilation error: 'Unresolved reference: exampleValue'
```